# Content page class method calling from master page class

Tags: asp.net, methods, master-pages

I have a public method in my content page class, I want to call this method from master page class.

Comment: If you do cphAdmin.Page as BasePage, it won't throw a NullReferenceException if the cast is unsuccessful. It will silently return null. So you'll actually have to do - BasePage page = cphAdmin.Page as BasePage); if (null != page) <do your stuff here>. The direct cast operator will throw a NullReferenceException if the cast is unsuccessful.

Comment: You can also take a look at this -
http://gen5.info/q/2008/06/13/prefix-casting-versus-as-casting-in-c/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can inherit your page from a base class. Then you can create a virtual method in your base class which will get overridden in your page. You can then call that virtual method from the master page like this -

```
(cphPage.Page as PageBase).YourMethod();
```

Here, **`cphPage`** is the ID of the **`ContentPlaceHolder`** in your master page. **`PageBase`** is the base class containing the **`YourMethod`** method.

EDIT: Of course, you'll have to put a null checking before you call the **`YourMethod`** method using the page's instance.

Comment: Excellant Idea!
I already have a base class that is inherited by page, so immediate the problem is solved.

Comment: Can you plz tell me what's the difference b/w both statement or these are same
(cphAdmin.Page as BasePage).yourmethod();
BasePage bp = (BasePage)cphAdmin.Page;
bp.yourmethod();

Answer (score 3):

if you do not want to use any base page

add this to your master page,

```
private object callContentFunction(string methodName, params object[] parameters)
{
    Type contentType = this.Page.GetType();
    System.Reflection.MethodInfo mi = contentType.GetMethod(methodName);
    if(mi == null)return null;
    return mi.Invoke(this.Page, parameters);
}
```

then use it

callContentFunction("myPublicMethodName", myParam1, myParam2...);

Comment: Reflection must be minimally used in an ASP.NET application especially in the presentation layer. And method invocation is one of the most unoptimized operation of Reflection.

Comment: "Reflection must be minimally used in an ASP.NET" why?

Answer (score 2):

STEPS:

1. Add New `<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="location of your masterpage" %>` directive to .aspx page
2. Declare one public function in MasterPage.
3. Call the function from content page using `Master.functionName()`.