# Accessing Content Page Method From MasterPage Method

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages, content-pages

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to call content Page function from Master Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8165930/how-to-call-content-page-function-from-master-page)

I need to access Content Page Method from Master page Event. How can I do this?

I saw this in stackoverflow But not able to know how to use it - [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887178/content-page-class-method-calling-from-master-page-class)

```
(cphPage.Page as PageBase).YourMethod();
```

Can you Explain this??

```
Content Page:

public partial class Call_Center_Main : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    public void MenuClick(string ClkMenu)
    { 
     // Some Code
    }
}


MasterPage:

public partial class MasterPage : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void Menu1_MenuItemClick(object sender, MenuEventArgs e)
    {
      //How Can I call MenuClick method from Content Page from Here  ???
    }
```

How Can I call `MenuClick` method from Content Page from `Menu1_MenuItemClick` in Masterpage ???

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8165930/how-to-call-content-page-function-from-master-page

Comment: try this http://odetocode.com/Articles/450.aspx

Comment: If you think this Question is an Exact Duplicate, then Provide me with a working answer (not the Links). Then vote to Close it.