# Calling Content Page Method from MasterPage Method

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages, content-pages

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [content page class method calling from master page class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887178/content-page-class-method-calling-from-master-page-class)

I need to access Content Page Method from Master page Event. How can I do this?

```
Content Page:
public partial class Call_Center_Main : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    public void MenuClick(string ClkMenu)
    { 
     // Some Code
    }
}

MasterPage:
public partial class MasterPage : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void Menu1_MenuItemClick(object sender, MenuEventArgs e)
    {
      //How Can I call MenuClick method from Content Page from Here  ???
    }
}
```

Comment: @Habib I know It is a Duplicate but I found this Answer after lot of effort. So I posted it so that someone needs It.

Comment: I am surprised that you found it after a lot of time, Its the 2nd result on [Google Search](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&tbo=d&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=Call+method+of+Content+page+from+master+page&oq=Call+method+of+Content+page+from+master+page&gs_l=hp.3..0i30j0i22.766.766.0.1369.1.1.0.0.0.0.303.303.3-1.1.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.CY-4G7FWlKQ&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=67a221e9661370f7&bpcl=38897761&biw=1280&bih=923) if you search by `Call method of Content page from master page`

Comment: And the [first result](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&q=Calling+Content+Page+Method+from+MasterPage+Method&oq=Calling+Content+Page+Method+from+MasterPage+Method&gs_l=hp.3...74225.74225.1.75008.1.1.0.0.0.0.239.239.2-1.1.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.bR_AaQS8mFU&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=67a221e9661370f7&bpcl=38897761&biw=1280&bih=923) if you search by title of your question

Comment: I saw that post and I made my requirement work using the Link from that answer. That is why I have posted the Link In my answer.

Comment: you can go this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8165930/how-to-call-content-page-function-from-master-page) and post your answer there with the code, but currently IMO your question is duplicate to existing questions on SO

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This answer is taken from [Interacting with the Content Page from the Master Page](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/master-pages/interacting-with-the-content-page-from-the-master-page-cs)

You can do this using Delegates.

For Example, you have a button in MasterPage and you want to call a Method in Content Page from Master Page. Here is the Code in Master Page.

Master Page:

```
public partial class MasterPage : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (contentCallEvent != null)
            contentCallEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
    public event EventHandler contentCallEvent;
}
```

Content Page:

```
public partial class Content_1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private void Master_ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // This Method will be Called.
    }
    protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Create an event handler for the master page's contentCallEvent event
        Master.contentCallEvent += new EventHandler(Master_ButtonClick);
    }
}
```

And Also add the Below Line Specifying you MasterPage Path in VirtualPath

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/MasterPage.master" %> 
// This is Strongly Typed Reference
```