# C# asp.net- How to access content page's method from master page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Guys how to access content page's method from master page in ASP.NET C#?

The code in content page (`usageDuration.aspx.cs`):

```
public void renderChart()
{
   // xxxxx
}
```

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/887178/content-page-class-method-calling-from-master-page-class

Comment: Possible Answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/887178/content-page-class-method-calling-from-master-page-class

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using delegates, for more information go through the below link

[Calling Content Page Method from MasterPage Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13620435/calling-content-page-method-from-masterpage-method)

your can find answer.